# How do I navigate with the dBeaver suggestion blocks?

Tags: sql, dbeaver

[image]

I always use the shortcut for selects (ctrl+shift+space) but then I need to click to edit thing like the where clause. Is there a keyboard shortcut for me to go from the table block to the column block and then value?

I've tried tab, ctrl+tab and so on